# Entity Framework "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am getting the error

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of
>   IEntityChangeTracker

when trying to create a new entity and save it to the DB.

I understand the error and how it normally occurs, but in this instance all I am doing is creating a new entity and adding a few `int`s to it before saving, not adding any other entities from other contexts.

I have included the function that is causing the error. As you can see it is being passed an `EndProduct` which is an entity which is being tracked by a different context to the one in the `_billableRepository`, but since I am not trying to in anyway assign that entity to the newly created billable I don't see how it can be a problem.

The only way I can see the error happening is because a couple of the `int` values that are being assigned to the new `Billable` are taken from the existing `EndProduct` that is being tracked by a different context, but surely the `IEntityChangeTracker` doesn't track the individual primitives of an entity?

```
public void AddBillable(EndProduct endProduct, int? purchaseId, string centreCode, int userId)
{
    if (endProduct.Product != null)
    {
        var existingBillableForUserForProductId = _billableRepository.GetQuery(b => b.UserId == userId && b.ProductId == endProduct.ProductId);
        if (endProduct.BillablePartId != null && !existingBillableForUserForProductId.Any())
        {
            var billable = new Billable {
                ProductId = endProduct.ProductId.Value, //int
                UserId = userId, //int
                PartId = endProduct.BillablePartId.Value, //int
                DateAdded = DateTime.UtcNow, //datetime
                PurchaseId = purchaseId, //int 
                CentreCode = centreCode //string
            };

            _billableRepository.Add(billable); //error here
            _billableRepository.UnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this. _billableRepository.Billable.Add(billable); _billableRepository.SaveChanges();

Comment: Are you disposing your context correctly each time? You should initialize it right before you need it and dispose it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The most likely cause of this is to do with any dependency injection tool you're using.

There should only be one `DbContext` in play per unit of work. If you are newing up a new one each time, make sure the old one is disposed of.

Otherwise, you will have multiple instances of the same context running alongside each other.

This is where the change tracker gets confused and is unable to track changes to your entities.

Comment: You are probably right. At the moment we are injecting a context per repository, so we definitely _do_ have multiple concurrent contexts. Its something we are trying to update throughout the whole code base. In the mean time there is no easy way to switch to a single context per request or similar. However I didn't think it would matter here because as far as I can tell, only one context is really in play here, the one for `_billableRepository`

Answer (score 5):

On your model `(GetById method)` try to put something like this:

`var billable = _db.Billable.`**AsNoTracking()**`.SingleOrDefault(i => i.BillableId == id);`

Use **AsNoTracking()** so that it returns a new query where the entities will not be cached in the `System.Data.Entity.DbContext`

Comment: This is the best !

Comment: @TelsonAlva Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can fix by attaching your entity in the repository. Like this:

```
_context.Set<T>.Attach(entity)
```

Where Set its your DbSet in the context.

Comment: This won't help if the entitty is already attached to a different instance of context...

Answer (score 0):

This sample code will solve the problem;

```
public class DataModel
    {
        private static DBContext context;
        public static DBContext Context
        {
            get
            {
                if (context == null)
                {
                    context = new SozlukContext();
                    return context;
                }
                return context;
            }
        }
    }
 public class EntryRepository : IEntryRepository
    {
        DBContext _context = DataModel.Context;
        public IEnumerable<Data.Model.Entry> GetAll()
        {
            return _context.Entry.Select(x => x);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written

Comment: I think everything is clear. I have a connection and an invoke operation. The connection is static and is called once. If the inside is full it turns itself. Thus the connection is made once.

Comment: Having a static `DbContext` is alaways considered to be a bad practice. It can lead to Memory Overhead, Problems with MultiThreading (`DbContext` is not Threadsafe), and much more. Alaways use one per whatever you define a *Unit of Work* and be aware of which `Entity` depends on which `DbContext`. If a `DbContext` is Disposed, you can either connect the Entity to another Context or work with a *Disconnected Entity* where all Data Needed is already cached *(Eager Loading)*. Lots of Information for this Topic can be found in the Web.

Comment: i will searching but I tried and don't meet to any error.