# Error when trying to use EF Functions with Generic IRepository Pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, design-patterns, irepository

i have implemented the Generic Repository Pattern in my app , with unity container as DI provider but when i start testing if it works or not this error appear " An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker "

my Repository Code

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
        T Get(int id);
        T Add(T item);
        bool Update(T item);
        bool Delete(T item);
        IEnumerable<T> Find(Func<T, bool> predicate);
        void Save();
    }

    public class Repository<M, T> : IRepository<T> where T : class where M : DbContext, new()
    {
        private ILogger _Log;

        public Repository(ILogger log)
        {
            _Log = log;
        }

        private M _entities = new M();
        public M Context
        {

            get { return _entities; }
            set { _entities = value; }
        }

        public T Add(T item)
        {
            try
            {
                _entities.Set<T>().Add(item);
                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _Log.LogErorr(this.GetType().Name + "Add Method", ex.Message + "--" + ex.InnerException);
                throw;
            }
        }

        public virtual bool Delete(T item)
        {
            try
            {
                _entities.Set<T>().Remove(item);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _Log.LogErorr(this.GetType().Name + "Delete Method", ex.Message + "--" + ex.InnerException);
                throw;
            }

        }

        public IEnumerable<T> Find(Func<T, bool> predicate)
        {
            IEnumerable<T> query = _entities.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
            return query;
        }

        public T Get(int id)
        {
            return _entities.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault();
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
        {
            IEnumerable<T> data = _entities.Set<T>();
            return data;
        }

        public bool Update(T item)
        {
            try
            {
                _entities.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                _Log.LogErorr(this.GetType().Name + "Update Method", ex.Message + "--" + ex.InnerException);
                throw;
            }
        }

        public virtual void Save()
        {
            try
            {
                _entities.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _Log.LogErorr(this.GetType().Name + "Save Method", ex.Message + "--" + ex.InnerException);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then i try to add some dummy data to the DB by this code and inject the controller with service

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
 private IRepository<account> _AccountRepository;
        public HomeController(ILogger Log,
                              IRepository<account> AccountRepository)
        {
            _Log = Log;
            _AccountRepository = AccountRepository;
        }
account ac = new account()
 _AccountRepository.Add(ac);
_AccountRepository.Save();

}
```

Comment: You likely have multiple instances of your DbContext. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37990476/2167293

Comment: Generic repo on top of db-context is just over engineering with no real achievement.

Comment: Agree with @jpishko. Your DI container (hopefully you are using one), should only be using one instance of IRepository<account> wherever it is needed.

Comment: thanks all its fixed i just remove the DataModel from Controller and every thing going good thanks

Comment: @niksofteng there absolutely are benefits to using a generic repo.  This makes it possible to switch to a different ORM (for example) or add custom error logging (as is done here), just to name a couple.

Comment: Repository pattern hides data access tech, generic repo is not mandatory for that. Generic repo is just about separating CRUD ops, however, it then indicates that all the entities support CRUD operations, but that is not always a case in real world. There could be an entity Y that cannot be deleted unless you delete entity X (I am not talking about referential constraints).